# Pass a string to a second view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to pass a string to a second view controller. The string is the title of the new view controller.
To pass the string I can use 2 solutions and both solutions work correctly but for me is not so clear the difference. Can someone explain me the differences?

Here the first solution:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "settime") {
            let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! timeSetting;
            //Assign the new title
            svc.toPass = "New Title"

        }
    }
```

Here the second solution:

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "settime") {
            let svc = segue.destinationViewController as? timeSetting;
            //Assign the new title
            svc!.toPass = "New Title"

        }
    }
```

The variable toPass is defined in this way in the second viewController:

```
 var toPass:String = "Title"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both solutions will perform the same action. In my opinion, the first solution is preferred because it express your intent more precisely.

By stating `let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! timesetting` you state that the destination view controller is certain to be of the type `timesetting`.

The second form tests to see if the destination view controller is of the type `timeSetting`. If it is, then the variable `svc` will have a non-nil value.

If you were to define another segue of the same name that presents a different type of view controller, then both solutions will fail; the first one on the `as!` clause and the second one when you try to unwrap `svc!`, which would be nil.

Comment: Oh, and by convention, class names should start with a cap, so rename `timeSetting` to `TimeSetting`.

Comment: You reply is complete, clear and detailed . Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Both of your code is working and it works in the same way.

The only difference is about the optional casting.

[Optional in Swift](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/swift-optionals-use-let/)

Comment: Thanks for the article... seems complete and I'll study it. I come from Obj-C and is not easy for me to understand the difference between ? and !

Answer (score 1):

They are the same.

If there is a difference, it is the time of unwrap the optional value. In the first solution, the type of `svc` is `timeSetting`. In the second solution, the type of `svc` is `timeSetting?`.

Answer (score 1):

Both will work but in my opinion the best way is to unwrap the optional like the following:

```
if let svc = segue.destinationViewController as? timeSerting { svc.toPass = "xx" }
```